# Find U coordinates of V

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, orthonormal, change-of-basis, gram-schmidt

I was practicing for an upcoming exam where I came across this question (in image). I don't have a majorly specific question -- I genuinely just didn't know where to start (though I suspect it may have to do with Gram Schmidt since only v2 is given) with this question and would love an explanation that's more in detail than the one in the image below:

[U-Coordinate Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgXc0.png)

Comment: For preparing for an exam when you are completely lost, it is always good to start by reviewing your lecture notes. If you don't understand the "solution" in your linked image, you may explain to the readers *which part* exactly you don't understand. Also, typing the image out in the post could help you think.